# Can I predict if it is better to save money in USD or local currency?

Tags: savings, foreign-exchange

I live in Egypt where the economy isn't that good.
[This table shows you the price of one USD in Egyptian pounds (EGP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_pound#/media/File:Us_dollar_value_in_egyptian_pounds.JPG) till 2010.

After 2010, The value of one USD was increasing.

In 2015, 1 USD = 8 EGP.

In 2016, 1 USD = 18 EGP !!

This year, USD fluctuates between 17 and 20 EGP.

For the Egyptian banks, The annual interest rate ranges from 8% to 10% and this year it is 10%

I do not know the optimal solution but I feel like it's better to save money in USD. What do you think?

Comment: I think a discussion on how to estimate an asset allocation percent range in foreign denominated savings is on-topic.  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the higher interest rates in local currency cover about the potential gain from the currency exchange rate change - if not, people would make money out of it. However, you only know this after the fact, so either way you are taking a risk.

Depending on where the local economy goes, it is more secure to go with US$, or more risky. Your guess is as good as anyone.

If you see a chance for a serious meltdown of the local economy, with 100+% inflation ratios and possibly new money, you are probably better off with US$. On the other hand, if the economy develops better than expected, you might have lost some percentage of gain.

Generally, investing in a more stable currency gets you slightly less, but for less risk.